# Использование строковых ресурсов из новой директории

Tags: android, android-resources

В папке `values` создал новую директорию`newValuesDirectory` с единственным файлом:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно, также внёс изменения в `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.test"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    //->->->->->->Внесённые изменения->->->->->
    sourceSets{
        main{
            res.srcDirs =
                    [
                            'src/main/res/values/newValuesDirectory',
                            'src/main/res'
                    ]
        }
    }
    //<-<-<-<-<-Внесённые изменения<-<-<-<-<-
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

В файле `newValuesFile.xml` имеется лишь одна строка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="test">Тест</string>
</resources>
```

Однако при вызове текста через `textView.setText(R.newValuesFile.test)` или `textView.setText(R.string.test)` выдаёт ошибку `Cannot resolve symbol`.

Подскажите, каким образом TextView можно установить текст из файла `newValuesDirectory.xml`?

Спасибо.

Comment: Хм, интересный вопрос. Ведь папка res у нас имеет жесткую структуру. Я знаю, что можно делать подпапку типа Resource, но вот так.  Я считаю, что даже если вы пропишите полный путь к вашей вложенной папке в gradle, то с values такое не прокатит, там нет вложенных папок он будет чекто брать данные напрямую с R.string... и тд. А вот с layout, может получится, но нужно тестировать.

Comment: В том то и дело, что судя по этому вопросу 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders проблем с layout не возникает. Однако хотелось бы для удобства использовать несколько строковых ресурсов. Правда, я не знаю, возможно ли это вообще осуществить.

Answer (score 1):

C созданием папок в `res/values`, вроде, не должно заработать, но можно создать в `res/values` отдельный файл, в коий можно поместить строковые (да и другие) ресурсы. Но вызывать их в коде надо будет также, как и обычные - через их тип.

```
textView.setText(R.string.test)
```